# PyQT QTableiew icon in vertical header

Tags: header, pyqt, icons, tableview

I'd like to show icons instead of texts in the vertical header of a QTableView.

Here's the QAbstractTableModel definition:

```
class clueTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    header_labels=['#','DESCRIPTION','TEAM','TIME','DATE','O.P.','LOCATION','INSTRUCTIONS','RADIO LOC.']
    def __init__(self,datain,parent=None,*args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self,parent,*args)
        self.arraydata=datain

    def headerData(self,section,orientation,role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role==Qt.DisplayRole and orientation==Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.header_labels[section]
        return QAbstractTableModel.headerData(self,section,orientation,role)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata)
    ...
    ...
```

And here's where the tableView is created:

```
class clueLogDialog(QDialog,Ui_clueLogDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui=Ui_clueLogDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.tableModel = clueTableModel(parent.clueLog, self)
        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.tableModel)

        self.ui.tableView.verticalHeader().setVisible(True)

        pixmap=QPixmap(":/radiolog_ui/help_icon.png")
        self.ui.tableView.model().setHeaderData(0,Qt.Vertical,pixmap,Qt.DecorationRole)
        self.ui.tableView.model().setHeaderData(1,Qt.Vertical,pixmap,Qt.DecorationRole)
        self.ui.tableView.model().headerDataChanged.emit(Qt.Vertical,0,1)
```

The result is that the vertical header items are just row number texts (the default).

I also tried it as a QIcon instead of a QPixmap with the same results.

I've also tried doing this in the headerData function of clueTableModel, like so, also with the same result:

```
    icon = QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/radiolog_ui/SplitterPanelIcon.png"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
    if role==Qt.DecorationRole and orientation==Qt.Vertical:
        return [icon,icon,icon]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Even though the headerData solution works below, it would be nice to find out why the attempts in the original question don't work: making the pixmap in every headerData call is wasteful and probably slow for large tables; doing it in the clueLogDialog would be better.

Comment: addressed the inefficiency some by defining the pixmap as an object variable during clueTableModel __init__ (can't define it as a class variable because there is no application gui (prerequisite for creating a QPixmap) at class creation time)

Answer (score 2):

Discovered the answer a few minutes after posting: do it in the headerData function of the model, but use a QPixmap instead of QIcon.  Also, return an empty string for the DisplayRole so as to suppress any default row numbering text:

```
def headerData(self,section,orientation,role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    if orientation==Qt.Vertical:
        if role==Qt.DecorationRole and self.arraydata[section][0]!="":
            return QPixmap(":/radiolog_ui/help_icon.png")
        if role==Qt.DisplayRole:
            return ""
    if role==Qt.DisplayRole and orientation==Qt.Horizontal:
        return self.header_labels[section]
    return QAbstractTableModel.headerData(self,section,orientation,role)
```

note, the above answer also has a filter to not display an icon if the first element of the data row is blank.

Hopefully this is useful to someone out there.